# How to avoid object injection from cookies?

Tags: php, security, serialization, cookies, code-injection

I need to store structured data in a cookie.
favorites of some catalog page. the data is `{ {id,type} , {id,type} , ... }`
In my code i need to put it back to a an array. so i am using the `unserialize()` function to recover the data.
Is there a way to prevent object injection? any alternative for the unserialize function?

Comment: are you sure a cookie is the place to store this ? (hint: probably not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent object injection

When you unserialize an object, PHP will call the `__wakeup` method in the class' definition (this is not stored in the cookie but in your PHP class file on the server).

Would it be possible for someone to change the serialized object's class and guess correctly causing a `__wakeup` function to perform some task? Yes. Usually `__wakeup` functions will simply reconnect to a resource so this may or may not be a big deal but why risk it? Just store the array as JSON with `json_encode($yourdata)` and get it back with `json_decode($cookiedata, true)`

As long as the data being stored client-side does not pose a security risk (i.e., reveals sensitive information) it's fine. Storing a user's favorites can be appropriate for this, especially if it's a high traffic site and you don't want to have to perform a database fetch or long sessions for this type of data.

Comment: thank you. for some reason i didn't thought about using json_decode :-?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a defined structure of how your array should look, then just make sure that the string you're unserializing is really an array when you're iterating over it just check the value type (id -> int, type -> string).

Plus, I think json_encode will be better in your case of data, it is smaller in size and faster in decoding (and you can work with it on the client-side).

Comment: nothing stops the client from messing up with any cookie. If you want to be sure that this data haven't been edited by the client, save it in session.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm thinking about would be to encrypt the cookie information, to prevent the user from knowing what the hell is he/she editing

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want the user to potentially modify the data, then don't give the data to the user in the first place. Use `$_SESSION`, a database, or write the info to a file on your server.